# How to resolve or ignore in xlsx2csv "Error: potential invalid date format."

Tags: csv, terminal, xlsx

I converted a .ODS file to .XLSX via libreoffice in terminal. Now I want to convert that .XLSX file into .CSV. (Going from .ODS to .CSV apparently only does the first sheet in a workbook, but you can get all the sheets in separate .CSV from .XLSX using xlsx2csv, as I found from a bunch of googling and the best answer to summarize it was here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042624/how-to-split-an-ods-spreadsheet-file-into-csv-files-per-sheet-on-the-terminal)

But whenever I run

```
~$ ~/.local/bin/xlsx2csv -a "/home/username/Pictures/folder/folder/XLSXDepot/file.xlsx" "/home/username/Pictures/folder/folder/XLSXDepot"
Error: potential invalid date format.
```

I get this error that all the google results are not quite getting me there.

Some results are identifying that dates prior to 1900 are not compatible with the script. That's cool and all, except, I have no dates in this workbook. It's misreading a number or string as a date stamp and breaking itself. So like searching a needle in a haystack to even track down what it is not liking.

Some google results show some way to pass ignore_formats to it; but I can't figure out how to do that in bash.

The help page also spits out this:

```
  --ignore-formats IGNORE_FORMATS [IGNORE_FORMATS ...]
                        Ignores format for specific data types.
```

But it doesn't tell me *what* is an acceptable value for IGNORE_FORMATS. I've tried "date", "dateformat", DATEFORMAT, DATE, "DATE", "DATEFORMAT", date, and dateformat. Wrapping things in quotes or changing caps and they all keep giving me the same error. I'm trying to put this flag in prior to the -a in the command.

Is there anyone who's googlefu is amazing and can track down some manpages that describe what acceptable values to the --ignore-formats flag is? Because the closest I got was an ubuntu manpages website and it didn't even mention the --ignore-formats flag at all.

That using a built in flag would work, --ignore-formats but I cannot find what an acceptable value is at all for this.

Comment: I’d try [GoCSV’s xlsx](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#xlsx) sucommand, it doesn’t care about the data’s format.

Answer (score 1):

From the release notes of LibreOffice version 7.2:

The --convert-to csv:... command line spreadsheet conversion or export filter options string accepts a new optional 12th numeric parameter, which makes it possible to export the entire document to individual sheets .csv files or a specified sheet. tdf#135762 (Caolán McNamara, Red Hat; Eike Rathke, Red Hat)

For example:

```
soffice --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":44,34,UTF8,1,,0,false,true,false,false,false,-1 sample.ods
```

0. or absent means the default behaviour, first sheet from command line, or current sheet in macro filter options, exported to sample.csv

-1. for all sheets, each sheet is exported to an individual file of the base file name concatenated with the sheet name, for example sample-Sheet1.csv, sample-Sheet2.csv and sample-Sheet3.csv

2. or any other 1-based number within the range of number of sheets for one specific sheet, here sample-Sheet2.csv

(source:  https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.2#Document_Conversion )

The first 9 options for `--convert to csv:` are here: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options#Filter_Options_for_the_CSV_Filter

P.S. Still searching for the docs on the other options....